# Multiple types for a property in an interface

Tags: flot, typescript

I've been working on creating a ambient definitions file for flot as an exercise in learning some TypeScript, but I've encountered this problem multiple times in the documentation for flot (in the axis options):

```
ticks: null or number or ticks array or (fn: axis -> ticks array)
```

So I could do this in my axisOptions interface:

```
interface axisOptions {
    ticks?: any;
}
```

Which covers all possible options, but is there a better way to restrict it to a number, an array (of numbers) or a function, but not anything else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't currently specify multiple types - in fact this is the perfect use of the dynamic `any` type because although it isn't "anything" it is certainly dynamic.

To enforce the types on a dynamic type, you would have to check it - like in this example:

```
function example (input?: any) {
    alert(typeof input);
    if (typeof input !== 'undefined' && typeof input !== 'string' && typeof input !== 'number') {
        alert('no');
        return;
    }

    alert('yes');
}

example(true);
example('Okay');
example();
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. Since I'm trying to write the definitions for somebody else's library, I'm not going to change the library itself. I was just hoping to get a little more compile type checking.

Comment: That's fair enough - if you were writing a library from scratch, you might opt to have separate methods and properties that you could statically type so you could have a firm contract - but the `any` dynamic type is excellent for integrating existing libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish some of what you are after by having multiple method definitions

```
interface lodash extends lodashProto, lodashStatic {
  (value: Array): lodashCurried;
  (value: Object): lodashCurried;
  (value: string): lodashCurried;
  VERISON: string;
}
```

Comment: But this is for a property. This isn't overloading a method.

Comment: yeah, so you have to create a typed wrapper. The wrapper could have entirely different methods, or use overloaded functions. I wish there was a way to specify a sum (union) type :(